# iOS 11 [MTLDebugTexture release] : message sent to a deallocated instance

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, core-image, metal

I'm developing an application that uses the Apple SpriteKit and CoreImage framework. On iOS 10 the application starts and is fluid, but on iOS 11 the application stops and after using the profiling tool "Zombies" I get the message

> [MTLDebugTexture release]: message sent to a deallocated instance

(more precisely, it is an instance of AGXMetalA8X that is accessed by jet:: create_texture () but which has been deallocated before by CoreImage... All of those classes belong to frameworks, not to my app)

I've tried many solutions proposed in response to this type of error, but the problem doesn't seem to be directly related to my code.

By adding the option "PrefersOpenGL = YES" in the Info.plist file there is no more this error. However, the graphics rendering is very bad with this option enabled.

I also tried to keep strong references to all the SKNode elements I create and to reduce memory consumption but this only delays the error. Moreover, it is not a very memory-intensive application (about 40MB of RAM consumed, on average, no apparent leak)

XCode 9 , Swift 3.2 , SDK iOS 11

Comment: did you try putting it into an autorelease pool? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, but it doesn't change anything, the error appears (and always so quickly)

Comment: ok then no idea,  you have something that is trying to call release on something already deallocated,  This bug may have always existed for you, but due to how it was running prior to 11, you may have never ended up in a state where you were releasing something already deallocated.  Without seeing code it is hard for the community to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't init the object and its seems to render before the allocation. You can fix this using the `awakeFromNib` method. Like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    createScene()
}
```